# create register page with different roles in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a system has 2 roles (teacher and student) the student can register straightforward as in drupal.
the issue now: I need the teacher to register with teacher role but the account status by default be inactive then the system admin activate it (request to join form).

is this applicable in drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by 'Muhammad Reda', you need to use Profile2 and Profile2 registration path contrib modules to have two different register forms.

And then you need to implement hook_user_presave (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) in your custom module and need to modify $edit array to change the status of the user to 0 so that teacher user gets registered in inactive state and admin can approve it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) contrib modules (Install the both). Both allow you to set different registration page for each role, role specific fields and more.